# Como encontrar uma tag "<li>" com um texto "dormitórios" de uma lista de tags, no python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou aprendendo a programar agora, e o python é primeira linguagem que estou trabalhando e estou com dificuldade para capturar a tag:

```
<li> 4 dormitórios
```

do html abaixo:

```
<div class="crop">
<ul style="width: 500px;">
<li><strong>587 m²</strong> de área útil</li>
<li><strong>1089 m²</strong> Total</li>
<li>
<strong>4</strong>
           dormitórios                                            </li>
<li>
<strong>4</strong>
       suítes                                            </li>
<li>
<strong>8</strong>
        vagas                                            </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

estou usando estou usando o find com regex, na expressão abaixo:

```
bsObj.find("div",{"class":"crop"}).find("ul",li=re.compile("^\d*[0-9](dormitórios)*$"))
```

mas ele retorna none, o que está de errado no código?

Answer (score 2):

A tag `<strong>` no meio do `<li>` estraga um pouco a busca da maneira que está a fazer. No entanto pode abordar o problema também desta forma:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '<div class="crop"><ul style="width: 500px;"><li><strong>587 m²</strong> de área útil</li><li><strong>1089 m²</strong>Total</li><li><strong>4</strong>dormitórios</li><li><strong>4</strong>suítes</li><li><strong>8</strong>vagas</li> \</ul></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll('li')
dorms = [i for i in data if i.text.startswith('4') and i.text.endswith('dormitórios')]
print(dorms)
```

Fica com uma lista dos `<li>` que têm "4" e "dormitórios" entre as tags.

Se quiser o que está entre as tags `<li>` mas sem outras tags pode:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '<div class="crop"><ul style="width: 500px;"><li><strong>587 m²</strong> de área útil</li><li><strong>1089 m²</strong>Total</li><li><strong>4</strong>dormitórios</li><li><strong>4</strong>suítes</li><li><strong>8</strong>vagas</li> \</ul></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll('li')
dorms = [i.text for i in data if i.text == '4dormitórios']
print(dorms)
```

Para conseguir só o número de dormitórios pode só usar regex:

```
import re

html = '<div class="crop"><ul style="width: 500px;"><li><strong>587 m²</strong> de área útil</li><li><strong>1089 m²</strong>Total</li><li><strong>4</strong>dormitórios</li><li><strong>4</strong>suítes</li><li><strong>8</strong>vagas</li> \</ul></div>'

dorms = re.findall('Total</li><li><strong>(.*?)</strong>dormitório', html)
print(dorms) # ['4']
```

Comment: mano, mas como é que faço agora pra ele trazer só o número, porém o número pode variar, pois estou lendo várias urls com a mesma estrutura, ai o texto pode ser "dormitório" ou "dormitórios" [s] e a quero capturar somente o número?

Comment: Ainda mais facil @JeuDomingos. Vou colocar em cima